# CAM application to generate G-Code

Tags: windows, gratis, cam

I rarely have access to a CNC milling cutter. Such milling cutters can process [G-Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-code). That G-Code again, is produced by CAM (computer aided manufacturing) tools.

I hardly know something about those machines, but I can design the objects in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), then export the data to various formats (DXF at the moment) and import that data in the CAM tool.

Until now I have used [CamBam](http://www.cambam.info/) and, let's say "it works" for me, since I do most work in Inkscape and I have been taught what to do in CamBam as the next step.

However, the trial period of CamBam is over now and I somewhat refrain to pay the $100, because I produce only a few pieces per year. Therefore I'm looking for a replacement that is free (gratis).

Requirements:

- import any of the file formats that Inkscape can export
- add the 2.5D data that's missing in the Inkscape file
- produce G-Code for the CNC milling machine
- runs on Windows 10
- gratis / free

My research:

- [MeshCAM](https://www.grzsoftware.com/) is a commercial product with 15 days trial period
- [CAMotics](http://camotics.org/download.html) seems to be unable to import any of the Inkscape formats